# Alternate way of usleep inside infinite loop for recieving msg from socket

Tags: c++, c

In infinite while loop I am continously checking for a received message from socket and using usleep() in the loop. But I want the alternate way to do it without using usleep() inside infinite loop. How to do it??

Comment: Example :     while(1) { recv(fd,buffer,size,NULL); usleep(100); }

Comment: As @user3386109 suggested you could use `select`, see for example http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#selectman

Comment: also to reduce CPU usage. select() will increase CPU usage

Comment: @AdnanKapasi No, it won't.

Comment: If you are having trouble using `select`, add the code you tried to the question.

Comment: can you please give an example on how to do it??

Comment: There is already a link to an example in the comments.

Comment: also i am using MSG_DONTWAIT in recv()

Comment: Can anyone please suggest some other way?

Comment: @AdnanKapasi Why?! Nothing you're doing makes any sense. For example, why would you specify `MSG_DONTWAIT` if you *want* to wait for a message? Just stop doing things you don't want to do and do what, and only what, you actually want!

Answer (score 2):

Just don't call `usleep`. I never understood why anyone would do something like that. Either use blocking sockets and block in `recv` or use non-blocking sockets and block in `select` or `poll`.

Follow the pattern of any sane example code you can find, but don't make up anti-patterns if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I already tried with select the way you are saying. But it increases the CPU usage.

Comment: @AdnanKapasi Likely because there was a bug in your code. Post a new question containing the complete code. It's very easy to misuse `select`. I'll even guess what you did wrong -- you forgot to reset the read set before *each* call to `select`. (If you can't get it to work the way it's supposed to work, trying a way that's not supposed to work is not a good strategy.)

Comment: Is there any other way except select??

Comment: @AdnanKapasi Blocking socket operations, poll, and many platform-specific ways such as epoll or IOCP.

Answer (score -1):

The execution of calling thread could make to sleep for a while by calling the usleep().
Another alternate way is to define a new Thread to mimic the interrupt (usleep) like waiting for a input from the keyboard or kind of signal(This needs to be periodic as the thread has to be resumed to process the response thread ).
but my suggestion would be why to make the things complex when there are simpler ways.